# WordPress posts load more button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, posts

i have custom php template for display all posts (from ACF). I need display only first 6 and after click on button load another 6.

My code:
JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".content").slice(0, 6).show();
  $("#loadMore").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content:hidden").slice(0, 6).slideDown();
    if($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
    }
  });
  
})
</script>
```

PHP

```
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'dluhopisy',
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ){
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ){
            $the_query->the_post();
            $the_id = get_the_id();
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
```

Comment: If its unclear, you can write what exactly so i can edit. or write better question.